# Python: math.ceil trouble

Tags: python, math, ceil

Here is the issue:

```
>>> 16/float(1184000)
```

returns:

```
1.3513513513513513e-05
```

if I try to run math.ceil on this number, i get "1" instead of "2"

```
>>>math.ceil(16/float(1184000))
```

returns:

```
1.0
```

This seems odd, any ideas how to address this?

Comment: I apologize if you already know this, but your first result is expressed in [**scientific notation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).  1.351e-05 can also be written as 0.00001351.  And `ceil(0.00001351)` is, in fact, `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you missed the power : `-05`:

The number is actually:

```
>>> '{:.20f}'.format(16/float(1184000))
'0.00001351351351351351'
```

So the answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The number 1 is the smallest integer larger than 16/1184000.  That's what `math.ceil()` does.

1.3513513513513513e-05 is between 0 and 1, so your two answers are consistent.

The number above is read as "1.3513513513513513 times 10 to the negative 5th power."

Comment: Thanks John, mistook that for 1.3 not 0.0000135..  :)